# Saving checkboxes value on the browser cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I have a particular question, in my application  i need to save some configuration about checkboxes, radio inputs and some other stuff. Each one of this things could be different user by user and the users are a lot, so the question, is it possible to store the configuration in the browser cache without passing by the server?
If i'll use the server i'll need to make a call every time that the user change this configuration, and i don't want to overload the server with request.
If it is possible i need to do that in javascript, or better with the angularjs framework(but i don't think it can help) anyone have a similar experience? is it possible to do this kind of things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or [Jquery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)